# Problem with CLK in implementing counter in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am trying to implement counter which gives as output values from one to six, which I want to later put on 7 segment display on fpga. The problem is with `CLK`, `process` doesn't see value of `CLK` changing and simulation gives as output always set of values "1001111".

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity projekt is
    generic ( half_period : time := 10ms);
    port(Q : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0));
end projekt;

architecture a1 of projekt is
    signal CLK : std_logic := '0';
begin
    CLK <= not CLK after half_period;
    process(CLK)
        variable tmpQ : integer range 0 to 7 := 1;
    begin
        if ( CLK = '1' and CLK'event ) then
            tmpQ := tmpQ + 1;
            if tmpQ = 7 then
                tmpQ := 1;
            end if;
        end if;
        case tmpQ is
            when 1 => Q <= "1001111";
            when 2 => Q <= "0010010";
            when 3 => Q <= "0000110";
            when 4 => Q <= "1001100";
            when 5 => Q <= "0100100";
            when 6 => Q <= "0100000";
            when others => Q <= "1111111";
        end case;
    end process;
end a1;
```

Is it CLK not changing or program never enters if statement?

Comment: What are you simulating? RTL sim or netlist simulation? you cannot synthesise "after" statements, so if you're simulation is a netlist clock is probably stuck at '0'. Your code is only valid for simulation and will not work on an FPGA.

Comment: @Tricky I am doing simple waveform simulation using software "Quartus 2". Can you explain in more details what do you mean by "synthesizing "after" "?

Comment: Quartus simulator does a netlist simulation. So your clock is stuck at 0. You will need to perform an RTL simulation on something like Modelsim to see your clock actually clocking. But the point remains, this code will not work on real hardware (as demonstrated in the Q2 simulation).